# Audi 06 - Replace Thermostat

Tags: cooling-system, audi

My check engine light came up yesterday. Just brought it into Audi and they say I need to replace the thermostat with the note "cooling system malfunction)". They're charging $600.

Is this necessary to do now? I've got 70000 miles on the car.

Any advice?

Comment: What exact car is this?  I've done some searches for replacement procedures and it doesn't sound too hard, but they are on earlier than 2006.  For example, my 2005 S4, with a 4.2L V8 shoe-horned into the same engine bay that normally has a 2.0L engine would probably be much harder, likely requiring removal of the front-end (most work on it does :-).

Answer (score 3):

A thermostat failing after that sort of mileage isn't that unusual. On an older car, I'd say do it yourself - new 'stats are dirt cheap and easy to test and replace. However, a newer car like that may have more complicated electronics connected to it that prevent you from doing that - Hopefully some of our modern car experts can help there?